# How can i use Google Analytics in my ASP.NET WebApp

Tags: c#, asp.net, analytics

I created a Google Analytics Account and copied the tracking snippet into the head of my MasterPage in ASP.NET. But when i run the WebApp the Google Analytics Charts are still empty. Is it possible to use Google Analytics in ASP.NET when the WebApp runs on the localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all assuming that no JavaScript error exist on your code - you just copy/paste the tracking code from google analytics and its run as expected.

Now, for google analytics to track your page, its must find **the same url name that you see on your url on your browser**.

Because you probably see `http://localhost/`, or `http://192.168.1.1/` or something similar you need to change that name, to much the same name that you use on google analytics.

To do that you can use the `host` file, located on `c:\[windows]\System32\drivers\` folder.

There open the `host` file, and add a line that reflect the local ip and use a url name close to the public one with different sub-domain and setup that one on google analytics.

for example something like

```
192.168.1.1 local.mypublicname.com
```

then setup that `local.mypublicname.com` on google analytics as a new view - a test view (example : https://www.directom.com/google-analytics-subdomain-tracking/)

call your local site as `http://local.mypublicname.com` and there you go - its works.

For working more easy, I suggest to setup the local ISS and not run the visual studio web server... but you can do both of them, just need an extra setup on visual studio to say where is the first page - in this case the `local.mypublicname.com`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Google Analytics needed time but i didn't know that. Today the charts had some values.

Comment: @SmightyM8 Its also the live view - at least to me, its direct shown on live view.